# Swift REPL Unexpected Behaviour

Tags: string, pointers, swift, read-eval-print-loop

If I use the following code in Swift repl, I get unexpected results:

```
  1> func addA(s: String)->String { 
  2.     return s + "a" 
  3. } 
  4.  
  5. func addB(s: String)->String { 
  6.     return s + "b" 
  7. }
  8>  
  9> println(addA(""))
a
 10> println(addB(""))
b
 11> println(addA(addB("")))
ba
 12> let p = addA(addB(""))
p: ((String)) = {
  _core = {
    _baseAddress = 0x0000000100500060
    _countAndFlags = 2
    _owner = (instance_type = Builtin.RawPointer = 0x0000000100500040)
  }
}
 13> println(p)
ba
 14> let q = "a" + "b"
q: String = "ab"
```

why does declaring `p` produce this behaviour, while declaring `q` does not?

Comment: What "behavior"? `p` yields `ba`. Is that not what you expect? It looks like the right answer to me.

Comment: @matt, I gather the behaviour being referenced is that massive essay from the interpreter about what `p` is, the `core/base/blah/blah` stuff :-)

Comment: Well, if you work with the REPL for a while, that sort of thing ceases to be "unexpected", eh @paxdiablo ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All that's happening here is that the REPL is letting you look inside Swift at some of the underlying efficiencies. `p` is stored as some sort of function composition. When evaluation is needed, it is evaluated. If you didn't want to see the sausage being made, you should not have entered the sausage factory.

Comment: Sausage factory, nice one.